# Holes inside Siemens IQ700 Microwave, Are these holes causing the microwave to switch off?

Tags: equipment

So my ~11 year old Siemens IQ700 microwave oven has developed a number of small holes right through the enamel & metal on the inside - I noticed these when the microwave developed an issue where after running for a couple of seconds it resets itself and goes back into standby mode - the oven and grill functions work perfectly its literally only the microwave function. My question is, if i repair these holes will the resetting issue be fixed and if so what is the preferred method to fix them? - i can open it up and repair from the inside, probably using aluminum tape or something and then touch up the enamel

Comment: Are you sure your microwave has developed holes, or perhaps you just didn't notice them before? There are holes in quite a few places in a microwave, for good reason. I find it unlikely that the holes are causing your issue, and plugging them is unlikely to solve anything.

Comment: My microwave had an interesting feature - a single wire with a simple terminal crimp connector at its end, connected at one end, to a wire going to a safety off-switch (taking also inputs from door latches and heat sensors),  at the connector end most purposefully mounted to point at the oven chamber, without being connected to anything. The purpose was to act as an antenna: if the chamber starts leaking microwave radiation, it induces current in the wire and triggers a safety shut-off. I expect this is exactly what's going on with your microwave.

Comment: Yes it is possible the holes existed for some time before the issue started, I may check inside for this antenna like wire and run some tests

Answer (score 4):

It's possible that the holes are causing the problem, but it's also possible they'd been there for a while and you only noticed them because your microwave is broken.

In any case, if you try to repair the holes, you run the risk of accidentally creating a resonant circuit which could start a fire. You've gotten a good eleven years out of this microwave; now it's time to buy a new one.

Comment: I think it's an assumption to say they're been good years. It could have been a sucky 11 years, or just mediocre.

Comment: @GdD In German you say "Good [amount of time]" if it has been a bit longer than [amount of time]. "Good 11 years" <=> A bit more than 11 years and "11 good years" <=> 11 years that were good. No idea if Sneftel is german but they might have meant that

Comment: @SirHawrk, I know what a good amount of time means, this was purely a jokey comment.

Comment: Ah my bad. I wasn't sure if english was the same

Comment: Yes it is possible the holes existed for some time before the issue started, Id really like to repair it because unfortunately buying a replacement is not an option right now. Id really appreciate some repair ideas or things to check - i understand the risks while working on electronics and microwaves but i am not familiar with identifying this kind of problem